# Error Installing Java7 on Linux Centos Server

Tags: java, linux, centos

Good evening, Im trying to install Jre and Jdk 7 on a commandline Centos virtual private server but it keeps trying to install each HTML line on the Oracle download page instead of the actual file. I already downloaded the rpm files and theyre in the folder but I cant seem to install them. I apologize because I am new to the OS. Would someone kindly guide me? Thanks

I've tried rpm -ivh and rpm -Uvh and here's what I get

```
[root@user ~]# rpm -ivh jre-7u79-linux-x64.rpm
error: open of <html> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <head> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <title>Unauthorized failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Request</title> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <META failed: No such file or directory
error: open of NAME=ROBOTS failed: No such file or directory
error: open of CONTENT=NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <link failed: No such file or directory
error: open of rel=stylesheet failed: No such file or directory
error: open of type=text/css failed: No such file or directory
error: open of href=/errors/us/assets/hp-styles.css failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of /> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <link failed: No such file or directory
error: open of rel=stylesheet failed: No such file or directory
error: open of type=text/css failed: No such file or directory
error: open of href=/errors/us/assets/master-master.css failed: No such file     or directory
error: open of /> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <body failed: No such file or directory
error: open of style=margin: 0px failed: No such file or directory
error: open of bgcolor= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <div failed: No such file or directory
error: open of id=banner> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <table failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=100% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of border=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellspacing=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellpadding=0> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of rowspan=2 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=middle failed: No such file or directory
error: open of nowrap><a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of href=http://www.oracle.com><img failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/oralogo-small.gif failed: No such file     or directory
error: open of width=154 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=19 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of hspace=10 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=25 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of border=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ></a></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=right failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=top failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=70% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of nowrap failed: No such file or directory
error: open of class=padMid><div failed: No such file or directory
error: open of id=bannerMid> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </div></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=30% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=left failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=bottom failed: No such file or directory
error: open of nowrap></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=right failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=bottom failed: No such file or directory
error: open of nowrap failed: No such file or directory
error: open of class=padMid></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=30% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=left failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=bottom failed: No such file or directory
error: open of nowrap></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </table> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </div> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <!-- failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Header failed: No such file or directory
error: open of END failed: No such file or directory
error: open of //--> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <table failed: No such file or directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of CELLPADDING=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of CELLSPACING=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of WIDTH=100%> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <TD><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT=></TD> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><table failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=100% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of border=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellspacing=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellpadding=0> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=15></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><h1>Sorry!</h1></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of colspan=2>In failed: No such file or directory
error: open of order failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of download failed: No such file or directory
error: open of products failed: No such file or directory
error: open of from failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Oracle failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Technology failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Network failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you failed: No such file or directory
error: open of must failed: No such file or directory
error: open of agree failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of OTN failed: No such file or directory
error: open of license failed: No such file or directory
error: open of terms.</td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of colspan=2><strong>Be failed: No such file or directory
error: open of sure failed: No such file or directory
error: open of that...</strong></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><img failed: No such file or directory
error: open of alt= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of height=7 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=3> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Your failed: No such file or directory
error: open of browser failed: No such file or directory
error: open of has failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cookies failed: No such file or directory
error: open of and failed: No such file or directory
error: open of JavaScript failed: No such file or directory
error: open of enabled.</td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of colspan=2><img failed: No such file or directory
error: open of alt= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of height=7 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=3> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of You failed: No such file or directory
error: open of clicked failed: No such file or directory
error: open of on failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Accept License failed: No such file or directory
error: open of for failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of product failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you failed: No such file or directory
error: open of wish failed: No such file or directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of download.</td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of colspan=2><img failed: No such file or directory
error: open of alt= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of height=7 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=3> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of You failed: No such file or directory
error: open of attempt failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of download failed: No such file or directory
error: open of within failed: No such file or directory
error: open of 30 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of minutes failed: No such file or directory
error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
error: open of accepting failed: No such file or directory
error: open of the failed: No such file or directory
error: open of license.</td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of colspan=2><strong>From failed: No such file or directory
error: open of here failed: No such file or directory
error: open of you failed: No such file or directory
error: open of can failed: No such file or directory
error: open of go...</strong></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><IMG failed: No such file or directory
error: open of SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of BORDER=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of ALT= failed: No such file or directory
error: open of height=5></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </table> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <table failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=100% failed: No such file or directory
error: open of border=0 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=center failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellpadding=2 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of cellspacing=2> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=middle> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=right failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=top failed: No such file or directory
error: open of width=2%><img failed: No such file or directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of height=7 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=3></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of href=javascript:history.back(-1)>Back failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of to failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Previous failed: No such file or directory
error: open of Page</a></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of </tr> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <tr failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=middle> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td failed: No such file or directory
error: open of align=right failed: No such file or directory
error: open of valign=top><img failed: No such file or directory
error: open of src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif failed: No such file or     directory
error: open of height=7 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of vspace=3></td> failed: No such file or directory
error: open of <td><a failed: No such file or directory
error: open of href=http://www.oracle.com/us/sitemaps/index.html </tr> <tr     valign=middle> <td align=right valign=top><img src=/errors/us/assets/004894.gif     height=7 vspace=3></td> <td><a     href=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/index.html>OTN Homepage</a></td> </tr> </table> <br> <div id=footer> <table width=100%  border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0> <tr> <td width=50% class=legalese align=right valign=top>&nbsp;</td> <td width=50% class=legalese align=left valign=top >&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td width=50% class=legalese align=left valign=top>&nbsp;</td> <td width=50% class=legalese align=right valign=top><a class=legalese href=http://www.oracle.com/rss/index.html target=_top>RSS <img src=/errors/us/assets/feed-icon-14x14.png width=14 height=14 border=0></A><span class=navlink> | </span> <a class=legalese href=http://www.oracle.com/html/copyright.html target=_top>Legal Notices and Terms for Use</a><span class=navlink> | </span> <a class=legalese href=http://www.oracle.com/html/privacy.html target=_top>Privacy Statement</a><br /> </td> </tr> <tr> <td width=50% class=legalese align=right valign=top>&nbsp;</td> <td width=50% class=legalese align=left valign=top ></td> </tr> </table> </div> </td> <TD WIDTH=10><IMG SRC=/errors/us/assets/spacer.gif BORDER=0 ALT= WIDTH=10></TD> </tr> </table> </body> </html> failed: No such file or directory
```

Additionally when I try to install using yum installlocal. I get an error saying that the java file cant be opened, however these files are clean and straight from oracles website. Lastly I tried extracting tar.gz java files from Oracle's website but they also cant be opened. Would someone kindly guide me?

Comment: could you please do a ls -la at ~ and paste the result in your question please?

Answer (score 0):

Your file download failed! You're trying to install a 401 Unauthorized HTTP response rather than an RPM file. Probably something to do with that checkbox that makes sure you've read the terms and conditions (which I believe is set as a cookie)

This article will help you install JRE/JDK: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-centos-and-fedora

Comment: Yea thanks. I didn't notice that a cookie was involved so I downloaded directly from oracle.

Comment: Also I see many different folders for java jdk in Centos user/lib/jvm. How do I know which one is the correct version? And the jdk folder is combined with the jre folder (Jre directory inside jdk directory) unlike windows?

Comment: The JDK comes with a JRE (this is the same on Windows too). If Java has been installed correctly and updated the 'alternatives', you should be able to check the version with `java -version` and the location of the binary with `readlink -f $(which java)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with downloading it through browser and then be using it, as  "wget" won't have the cookies and the other information your browser already contains, like authentication into the Oracle site,